# Qt MainWindow ignores width, height and title properties

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I've created a simple Qt Widgets application using Qt Creator on my Windows 10 machine. I use the ui file and the designer to change properties of my QMainWindow, but somehow the width, height and windowTitle properties have no effect when I set them in the designer. Example:

[image: Designer look]

However, the resulting application looks like this:

[image]

Both size and windowTitle are seemingly ignored. I've also tried setting properties from code, like this (but to no avail):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("That's some title you've got there");
}
```

I have also added a layout to the centralWidget but that only had an effect on the child controls, not the actual window itself (and that seems logical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it should work.

Can you try if the following minimal example works for you?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow m;
  m.setWindowTitle("TEST");
  m.show ();
  a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, the windowTitle just defaults to the project name (I simply created a new Widgets application and added the line in main.cpp like you suggested) I did find 'windowFilePath' in the documentation but this has no effect either.

Comment: Maybe you should specify your qt version in your question. I tested it with Qt 5.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction. I was using Qt 5.7 for WinRT. I switched to 5.8 MSVC 2015 and the problem is gone.